# Pentaho Error - ConnectionServiceImpl.ERROR_0009 - Connection to database failed

Tags: oracle11g, pentaho

I'm trying to setup Pentaho connection with my Oracle DataWarehouse (localhost). However, this error "ConnectionServiceImpl.ERROR_0009 - Connection to database [DBNAME] failed" appears when I try to test the connection. 
The information about server should be right, and I also added the JDBC to the tomcat folder.

[image: Error capture]

Error capture

[image: Database Connection information]

Database Connection information

Answer (score 1):

Check your catalina.out log. You should have the cause of the error there. It could be a bad url, bad db name, bad credentials, missing jdbc driver, among many other reasons.

Catalina.out is inside your tomcat/logs folder by default.